# How to set textwidth when editing command line in vi mode

Tags: bash, vim

When I press `v` in readline's `vi` command mode, it opens the current command line in my editor (`nvim`, though I assume this is equally applicable to `vim`), and executes it on a save.

How can I automatically set `textwidth=0` when opening `nvim` in this way?

As an aside, what is the command mode `v` feature called? `man readline` doesn't show any binding for `v`, so I had some trouble titling this question.

Comment: Try setting your EDITOR to `nvim -c "set tw=0"`

Comment: See `man bash`, command `edit-and-execute-command`.

Comment: @glennjackman `EDITOR` is used for many other things, I don't want to disable `textwidth` for all of those

Comment: @phd thanks! I didn't realize this was a bash and not a readline feature. I'll fix the tags

Comment: close/down-voters, should this be on SuperUser? Or is there another issue?

Comment: I voted to move this to SuperUser because I don't think it's programming related, but I didn't downvote.